# Can I use a pure javascript es6 with a ASP,NET CORE MVC Multi-page Application?

Tags: ecmascript-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working in a asp.net core mvc application, and I would like to use a client side framework. Most of the code is made in razor, so I dont want something too complex as React, angular, etc...  So, how can I work with these two technologies at the same time? Can I create es6 javascript files just for specific mvc views?